# How to post only 1 value from selected list to controller code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have my select list options and I have conditional checks to associate each details to the individual options. Hence, when I submit the form, all the values are POST -ed to the controller code, which is not what I want. Hence, how am I able to only POST the details of the select option that has been selected by the user and not POST all the other details.

<..code..>

Hence, How am I able to only just POST one details associated to the option selected over to the controller code

**Issue solved**

Comment: You can do a check for the selection in the controller. This way all data is passed to the controller. But the controller does the filtering on what to save depending on the selection.

Comment: You could use jQuery and ajax post the selected input into the controller.

Comment: @odannyc To do a check at the controller?How do you suggest doing that? I feel that this may not be the right way, what if there are way more than 3 options and furthermore, how is the condition in the controller got  to do with the check

Comment: @Idealcastle Could you kindly guide me through?

Answer (score 0):

Untested:
A simple way would be to add the `disabled` attribute to the div, (in addition to display:none).

That would be probably something like:

```
 document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("disabled");
```

To remove the disabled attribute

```
document.getElementById("id").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Update:
Try Something like this :

```
function val(ddbox) {
    //NEW
    if ( ddbox.options[ddbox.selectedIndex].value == "Others"){
        document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("extradiv").removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("extradiv").setAttribute("disabled");
    }
    .
    . 
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask where should I be adding the following line to?

Comment: Make the element disabled when you are making its display:none. Where are you making its display to none ?

Comment: the display to none is made within the <script> where the condition checks on the value selected in the dropdown list, if the value selected is not equal then it wouldn't display the block else it would. Meanwhile, the default display of extra fields are set to none

Comment: strangely, it doesn't work as it will render the field views of the first options invisible, except for "Others"